# Write zip object to .txt file vertically

Tags: python, file, zip

I have several zip objects in python like this:

```
list(zipped1)
Out[84]: 
[(0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 782139),
 (0, 913408),
 (0, 956747),
 (0, 970377),
 (0, 1012808),
 (0, 3036503),
 (0, 7112396),
 (0, 7436273),
 (0, 7454654),
 (0, 7460688),
 (0, 8603961)]

list(zipped1)
Out[84]: 
[(0, 782139),
 (0, 913408),
 (0, 956747),
 (0, 970377),
 (0, 1012808),
 (0, 3036503),
 (0, 7112396)]
```

And I have a list of this objects `zippeds` I want to write the zip objects in a single text file concatenated vertically without the commas but with spaces like this:

```
0 2
0 3
0 5
0 782139
0 913408
0 956747
0 970377
0 1012808
0 3036503
0 7112396
0 7436273
0 7454654
0 7460688
0 8603961
0 782139
0 913408
0 956747
0 970377
0 1012808
0 3036503
....
```

Noted that the zeros in the first column is not always the case, just coincidence that all of them are zeros. I haven't much experience in working with file I/O and I can't figure out how to crack this one. Any help\direction would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you open a file? Do you know how to write to a file? Is the formatting of the string?

Comment: Note, you can just get the string using something like `'\n'.join(map(' '.join, data))`

Comment: but probably, you should just loop over and write each individual line, so `for x, y in zipped: file.write(f"{x} {y}\n")`

Comment: ```zipped``` is a list of zip objects, so with this I am getting too many values to unpack error.

Comment: But with an outer loop on ```zipped``` it seems to do the trick. Thank you very much if you want post a full answer so I can accept it.